# Ubuntu Icons Disappeared

Tags: gnome, icons, themes, gnome-tweaks

I am running Ubuntu 18.04.5, I have installed several themes and later on I decided that I don't need some of them. I have deleted their folders `usr/shared/icons & usr/shared/theme` folder and deleted them with `rm -r <name of folder` command.

All the icons have disappeared and shown as blank. I have installed Ubuntu on VM again and copied these folders to my Ubuntu install but lots of 3rd party apps are not showing icons. I changed theme from GNOME Tweaks and also tried resetting with

`gsettings set org.gnome.desktop.interface icon-theme "ubuntu-mono-dark"` 
`sudo apt --reinstall install light-themes`
`sudo apt install Ambiance`

These instructions didn't help. Is there any solution for this ?

Comment: You deleted the icons directory, so it makes sense that there are no icons to show on the screen. It might be possible to fix this by re-installing the theme(s) you want to use, otherwise you'll need to restore those directories from your most recent backup.

Comment: I have installed some of those themes especially the icons, now I have some of the icons back but the third party app icons are all missing and it shows a blue icon for all of them

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You probably need to install the theme ENGINES for these to work. for example, you may need
gtk3-engines-oxygen
gtk3-engines-unico
gtk3-engines-xfce
Depending on the type of icons, you will also need something like a file named index.theme
which makes available themes, icons, etc. available to the engine.
By simply adding folders manually, the engine (if it exists for those icons) can't use them.
If you install an icon set using, say, synaptic, it will tell you what dependencies you'll need.
Or, if you have .deb files to install, Gdebi is another tool often used which will check dependencies.
Yet another way to make sure desktop icons use a particular icon is to set the icon from the properties of the icon itself, and select a particular icon from a local folder. (Some executable icons won't allow this, however.)